# ¿Como puedo usar el Action Listener para asignarle unas teclas a unas imagenes?

Tags: java

quiero hacer un juego donde una serie de imágenes saldrán en pantalla. la idea es que si la imagen de color azul sale el niño oprima la letra (A) por ejemplo.
 si sale una verde oprima la letra (v), y de esta forma saldrá un mensaje de correcto pero si oprime otra que no corresponde salga error.
como le asigno una letra a cada imagen.

```
                          Imagenes = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/Estimulo_4.png"));                      
                          mysecuencia.jLabel1.setIcon(Imagenes);
                         break;


                     case 1 :
                       contador =2;
                        // System.out.println("");
                          Imagenes = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/Estimulo_1.png"));                      
                          mysecuencia.jLabel1.setIcon(Imagenes);
                         break;
                          case 2:
                           contador = 3;
                        // System.out.println("");
                          Imagenes = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/Estimulo_2.png"));                      
                          mysecuencia.jLabel1.setIcon(Imagenes);
                         break;
                          case 3:
                       contador = 0;
                        // System.out.println("");
                          Imagenes = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/Estimulo_3.png"));                      
                          mysecuencia.jLabel1.setIcon(Imagenes);
                         break;    

                          default:
                              System.out.println("se encontro un error al reproducir secuencia de imagenes,bbkfff");
```

Comment: una ayuda, concejo  por fa.

Comment: No tienes que asignar a la imagen en sí: tu aplicación (tu contenedor, por ejemplo) detectará la tecla pulsada y según la imagen que estés mostrando decidirá si se ha pulsado la tecla correcta o no. Es complicado ser más preciso si no hay un escenario bien definido: intenta empezar a crear la aplicación y cuando te atasques haz una pregunta más concreta, con un [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenes que implementar la clase `KeyListener` o la interfaz `KeyAdapter`, esta última es mejor ya que tenés que sobreescribir un solo método (para eso son las clases adaptadoras). Si ya usaste ActionListener, esto es lo mismo, así que no vas a tener ningún inconveniente. Acá va una muestra, al programa le tuve que agregar una ventana a modo de que el programa no finalice y se quede a la escucha del evento de teclado, pero vos en tu programa no vas a necesitar esa ventana.

```
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class EventosTeclado {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MarcoParaMantenerProgrActivo marco1=new MarcoParaMantenerProgrActivo();
        marco1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//cierra el programa al cerrar la ventana
    }

}

// ventana para mantener el programa activo para que se quede a la escucha del evento de teclado
class MarcoParaMantenerProgrActivo extends JFrame{

    public MarcoParaMantenerProgrActivo() {
        setVisible(true);
        setBounds(200, 100, 600, 450);

        EventoDeTecladoOyente tecla=new EventoDeTecladoOyente();
        addKeyListener(tecla);
    }

}
class EventoDeTecladoOyente extends KeyAdapter{

   @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        char letra=e.getKeyChar();//guardas letra que pulsó el usuario
        System.out.println(letra);
        char letraCorrecta='r';//asignas letra correcta dependiendo de la imagen

        if(letra == letraCorrecta) System.out.println("Respuesta correcta");
        else System.out.println("Respuesta incorrecta");
    }   
}
```

Cualquier duda consultame. Que estás usando para el mensaje "correcto o incorrecto" ? Te conviene usar `JOptionPane`

Comment: wow amigo gracias sos un pro, aunque me confunde
porque no entiendo me muestras como establecer la letra y el evento pero no como asignar celo a la imagen que tengo dentro del switch con un contador.

Comment: Para vincular la imagen con la letra correcta podrías asignar el valor de `letraCorrecta` en cada `case` del `suitch`, lo que si, `letraCorrecta` deberá ser una variable global, o sea para que el método `EventoDeTecladoOyente` la reconozca, se entiende? Pero como yo no conozco la estructura de clases de tu programa, vos vas a tener que decidir. Si no pasame mas cantidad de código. Bueno, proba y contame como te fue

Comment: te lo puedo mostrar al correo?
explicame con un pedacito de codigo

Comment: Es que creo que está mal visto en este sitio usar correos o enlaces externos para ver código. Hace una cosa, edita la pregunta y pega todo el código completo. No creo que sea demasiado largo. Si no se puede, avisame y vemos como hacer

Comment: que es muy largo no me deja

Comment: yo decía así, por ejemplo, dentro de `case 1`, la imagen `Estimulo_1` suponiendo que es de color rojo le asignas a la variable `letraCorrecta` el caracter 'r', así `letraCorrecta='r';`, antes la debes haber inicializado así `char letraCorrecta=null;`, en una parte de tu programa de manera que tanto`EventoDeTecladoOyente` como el método donde se encuentra el `switch` la reconozca (variable global). Lo ideal es declararla como atributo

Comment: proba pegar la clase entera donde se encuentra la parte de código que publicaste

Comment: no me lo permite

Comment: ok, buscame en fb como juan rom, me gustaría que termines tu proyecto

Comment: listo so se lo agrdezco